# Unable to find in App Store, able to redownload using iCloud?

Tags: icloud, backup

I obtained an app from the App Store that I can't find now or was it simply taken down, but I still have the app on my iPod. I'd like to install it on my other iPod.

I don't know that if I backup my iPod (iCloud backup) it'll still be there.

Can I install the app from my backup to my other iPod and still be sure to keep it on my original device?

Answer (score 5):

Connect each phone to iTunes over USB - choose to transfer all purchases to the computer. When all the apps are on iTunes, you can install them on devices that them even when the store online is "out of stock"

Comment: I manually backed up the one that has the app, but now how do I choose the other one. and tell iTunes to download the app to that one

Answer (score 2):

In **iTunes**, click on the Apps icon to see a grid of your downloaded apps.

[image: Apps Icon iTunes]

Plug your second iPod into your Mac/PC.

Drag the app to the new device.  (It should show automatically in the sidebar as you start to drag.) [Assuming you are using the latest version of iTunes.  It should work on previous versions as well.]

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to find the app in the App Store, even if it has been taken down. In the App Store app on your iPod, if you go to the Updates tab and you scroll up a little bit there is an option to see all your purchased apps. You can then tap "Not on This iPod" to find all the apps you've downloaded that aren't on that iPod, and it should be easy to find there.[image: Not on This iPhone]

Comment: According to [Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.com/download-flappy-bird-2014-2), it is possible

Comment: It depends - Apple can pull an app and no one can download it again. The developer can pull the app from sale but allow downloads to continue or the developer can pull the app and prevent downloads. The only sure fire way to know is talk to Apple or talk to the Developer. The only sure solution is to transfer the signed app using iTunes if you can't get it from the store.

Comment: It seems like it's at least worth checking